# Spresense SDK (IDE) ビルドのコンフィギュレーションに関して

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDK (IDE) で新規にプロジェクトを作成して、
例えば以下サンプルと同じことをしたいとき
\spresense\examples\camera
カーネル/SDKコンフィギュレーションで何を設定すれば良いのでしょうか？

上記はあくまでも例ですが一般的にサンプルの組み合わせ等を行うとき
どのコンフィギュレーションにチェックを入れたら良いのでしょうか？

コンフィギュレーションの個々のパラメータの説明資料があると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご質問の件について回答させていただきます。

CameraのExampleと同等の設定は、SDKコンフィグレーションを開き、 `新規作成` → `Examples` → `Camera` を選択することによって行うことができます。この操作で、CameraのExamplesをビルド対象に含める設定と、それを使用するために必要な設定(SDカードなど)を行っております。

[image: SDKコンフィグレーション]

このままでは `spresense/examples/camera` がビルド対象となってしまいますので、
新規作成ダイアログを保存し、SDKコンフィグレーション上でCameraのExamplesをビルド対象から外す必要があります。

[image: カメラの無効化]

複数のExamplesの組み合わせの場合も同様に設定を行うことができます。

尚、カーネルコンフィグレーションは通常の使い方であれば `release` を選択してください。

そして、各パラメータの説明はコンフィグレーション上に表示されるメッセージに表示されています。

[image: パラメータ説明]

また、新規作成ダイアログにある個々の機能につきましては、下記サイトにて公開しております。

[Examples 一覧](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_examples_%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7)

以上、ご参考になれば幸いです。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。コンフィグレーション上手く行きました。